# Multi Array - Counting Values of Elements

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
[id] => 1,
[value] => 100
)
[1] => Array(
[id] => 1,
[value] => 200
)
[2] => Array(
[id] => 1,
[value] = 300
)
[3] => Array(
[id] => 2,
[value] = 100
)
[4] => Array(
[id] => 2.
[value] => 200
)
)
```

How can I count sum of [values]'s of the elements with the same [id] and put to array like:

```
Array(
[1] => 600,
[2] => 300
)
```

? 
THANKS!

Comment: Basically, you're asking _us_ to do _your_ job here. Several words spring to mind, _"lazy"_ being one of the nicer ones

Comment: nah, im asking for help, because i'm stuck

Comment: Read the help section: you are asked to _show what you've tried_, Show us where you're stuck, so we can tell you what you've missed/done wrong, and why your code didn't work. ATM, you just show us some data, saying _"What I want is to end up with this"_ and ask us how to get there. It's like me asking you the way to some museum, without telling you where I am, if I'm lost or not, or if I'm sitting at home, drinking a nice beer and being too damn idle to use google maps

Comment: ok, i've heard you, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array=array(array('id'=>1,'value'=>100),array('id' => 1,'value' => 200),array('id' => 1,'value' => 300),array('id' => 2,'value' => 100),array('id' => 2,'value'=> 200));

$res=array();
foreach($array as $a)
{
    if(array_key_exists ($a['id'],$res ))
    {
        $res[$a['id']]+=$a['value'];
    }
    else
    {
        $res[$a['id']]=$a['value'];
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

**output**

```
 Array ( [1] => 600 [2] => 300 )
```